# How to test service function having $q promise with karma in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a service and inside that service, I have function like so

```
 settings.updateProfile = function(patient){
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            var user = patient;
                dbService.updateUser(user).then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.res) {
                            LoopBackAuth.setUser(LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId, response.res.name, LoopBackAuth.currentUserRole);
                            LoopBackAuth.save();
                            location.reload();
                            patient.name == response.res.name ? resolve(true) : resolve(false);
                        }
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                );

        });
    };
```

Here dbService.updateUser function contain $promise as well. I want to test this function and check if it resolved true or false. I know for http api call we use $httpBackend service. But It is not working as I am expecting. Right now I am testing it like this.

```
  it('Should return correct result', function() {
        var result = true;
        var patient = {"name": "newUser"};

        $httpBackend.whenGET(patient).respond(200, $q.when(result));
        expect(settingsFactory.updateProfile).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toEqual(true);

        settingsFactory.updateProfile(patient)
            .then(function(res) {
               result = res;
            });

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(settingsFactory.updateProfile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(patient);
    });
```

It showing error:

```
 Error: Unexpected request
```

Comment: You are not testing correctly you should first set up the $httpBackend to respond 200 when you endpoint is requested. Then call your service, and wait for the promise to test

Comment: I didn't get you completely. Can you please change my test and show it with code? Thanks

Comment: Just a comment about your code structure: if `dbService.updateUser(user)` returns a promise you don't need to use `$q` at all, just return that whole `dbService.updateUser(...).then(...)` expression and return `true` or `false` from inside the handler functions.

Comment: Ya, it would be better. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(patient).respond(...);
```

is failing because `patient` is an object `{"name": "newUser"}` and whenGET is expecting a string. For example:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/patient').respond(...);
```